# Getting a value of a key from an XML file in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file with the following structure:

```
<Definitions>
  <Definition Execution="Firstkey" Name="Somevalue"></Definition>
  <Definition Execution="Secondkey" Name="Someothervalue"></Definition>
</Definitions>
```

How can I get the values of the keys (Firstkey, Secondkey) and write them down using C# in my .NET application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Linq to XML this is straightforward.

To just get the keys:

```
var keys = doc.Descendants("Definition")
              .Select(x => x.Attribute("Execution").Value);
foreach (string key in keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}", key);
}
```

To get all values:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
var definitions = doc.Descendants("Definition")
                     .Select(x => new { Execution = x.Attribute("Execution").Value,
                                        Name = x.Attribute("Name").Value });
foreach (var def in definitions)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Execution = {0}, Value = {1}", def.Execution, def.Name);
}
```

**Edit in response to comment:**

I *think* what you really want is a dictionary, that maps from a key ("Execution") to a value ("Name"):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
Dictionary<string, string> dict = doc.Descendants("Definition")
                                     .ToDictionary(x => x.Attribute("Execution").Value, 
                                                   x => x.Attribute("Name").Value);
string firstKeyValue = dict["Firstkey"]; //Somevalue
```

Comment: This would print all the values. While I want to get the value of "Secondkey", for example and use it somewhere else. Like someLabel.Text = "SecondkeyValue".ToString();

Comment: Not sure if I understand this. Let's assume I want to get the value of "Secondkey" from the XML file and assign it to a variable. How am I going to do this? I do not want to get all the keys and values and print them. I want to be able to get the value of any key in the XML file and assign it to variable.

Comment: @cyero: Edited my answer - is this what you wanted?

Comment: XPath would be much easier, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Using XMLDocumnet/XMLNode(s):

```
//Load the XML document into memory
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("myXML.xml");

//get a list of the Definition nodes in the document
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Definition");

//loop through each node in the XML
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
   //access the key attribute, since it is named Execution,
   //that is what I pass as the index of the attribute to get
   string key = node.Attributes["Execution"].Value;

   //To select a single node, check if we have the right key
   if(key == "SecondKey") //then this is the second node
   {
      //do stuff with it
   }
}
```

basically you load the xml into a document variable, select the nodes you wish to view. Then iterate through them and store pertinent information.

Comment: Not sure if I understand this. Let's assume I want to get the value of "Secondkey" from the XML file and assign it to a variable. How am I going to do this? I do not want to get all the keys and values and print them. I want to be able to get the value of any key in the XML file and assign it to variable.

Comment: the `foreach` loop goes through every Definition node in your XML. When you are inside the `foreach` code block `node` refers to a single XML Definition node. I can access the attributes of that node via the `Attribute` property. So to get the keys I say `node.Attributes["Execution"]` where `"Execution"` is the name of the attribute.
**Edit:** Added more comments to hopefully clear things up

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

var keys = XDocument.Load("path to the XML file")
.Root
.Elements()
.Select(x => x.Attribute("Execution"));
```

Answer (score 1):

[XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath) would be a great choice, I'd say.

Below is a sample XPath expression.

`//Definition[@Execution='Firstkey']/@Name`

As a XPath expression is a string, you can easily replace 'Firstkey' with whatever you need.

Use this with a [XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.selectsinglenode.aspx) or [XmlDocument.SelectNodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.selectnodes.aspx) method

Both the above mentioned methods return an XmlNode. You can easily access the `XmlNode.Value`

[Here are some XPath expressions](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp)

Don't forget [XPath Visualizer](http://xpathvisualizer.codeplex.com/) which makes working with XPath so much easier!